# Spatial equivalent of attention "span"

Tags: word-choice

Attention span means the amount of time one can concentrate on a certain task. I am wondering what is the spatial equivalent to describe one's attention "space" as we are capable of perceiving and paying attention to a lot of different things simultaneously. Some like attention range/ attention realm came up in my head but I do not think they are the correct ones.

Comment: People usual say multitasking.

Comment: Adding to above, "ability to multitask" would convey what you are asking, although it lacks in brevity. The phrase "situational awareness" fits what your are looking for, although I'd imagine it is more limited than what you are seeking. Since span relates to length/distance, perhaps "breadth" would work although it would probably be confusing to use "attention breadth" as it's not a phrase already being used and thus would require an explanation.

Comment: How about "locus of cognition" or "field of cognition?"

Answer (score -1):

> horizont

which pertains to distance

> field of view

which pertains to, you know, the area of the visual plane that is in

> focus

which has a more general meaning, but means ***depth of field*** in optics. The ***focus range*** is the sum of all possible depths. If these are limited, one is either near- or farsighted

All these may reduced if starring to long at screens. But this doesn't capture what you want to say. Instead, some terms convey negative connotation, like *tunnel vision*.

But vision isn't static, if the rapid eye movement plays a role. Dexterity, felicity, velocity, aptitude, ... don't strike me as very focused on optics.